# Cannot display number values

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I just joined and hope to learn all I can here and contribute where I can.

I am having major issues with the last three sections of my VBA script. 
The correct, incorrect, and percentage score values are not being displayed on slides 40 & 41.

On slide 42 I cannot get the textbox or the label to display the username, date and their overall percentage score.

Any help on slide 40 would be great and I can workout the rest.

```
**Sub shapeTextHappySmile()**strong text**
Sub ShapeTextSadSmile() 
Sub CertificateBuld()**


Option Explicit
Dim UserName As String
Dim numberCorrect As Integer
Dim numberIncorrect As Integer
Dim numberPercentage As Integer
Dim numberTotal As Integer

Private Sub CertDate()
Dim Rdate As Variant
Rdate = Date
Rdate = Format((Date), "mmmm dd, yyyy")
End Sub

Sub Initialise()
numberCorrect = 12
numberIncorrect = 8
numberPercentage = 58
numberTotal = 20
numberTotal = (numberCorrect + numberIncorrect)
numberCorrect = (numberTotal - numberIncorrect)
numberIncorrect = (numberTotal - numberCorrect)
numberPercentage = Round(numberCorrect / numberTotal) * 100
End Sub

Sub TakeQuiz()
UserName = InputBox(Prompt:="Type Your Name!    ")
MsgBox "Welcome To The Academic Online Tutorial Quiz  " + UserName, vbApplicationModal, " Academic Online Tutorial Quiz"
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next
End Sub

Sub Correct()
numberCorrect = numberCorrect + 1
MsgBox ("Great well Done! That's the correct answer")
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next
End Sub

Sub Incorrect()
numberIncorrect = numberIncorrect + 1
MsgBox ("Sorry! That was the incorrect answer")
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next
End Sub

Sub shapeTextHappySmile()
ActivePresentation.Slides(40).Shapes(Label1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = 12
'numberCorrect
ActivePresentation.Slides(40).Shapes(Label2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = numberPercentage & "%"
MsgBox "Great Job, Well done " + "," & "Please print a copy of your completion certificate"
MsgBox "After printing or saving a copy of your certificate, you can exit the presentation"
With SlideShowWindows(1).View
.GotoSlide 42
End With
End Sub

Sub ShapeTextSadSmile()
ActivePresentation.Slides(41).Shapes("AnsweredIncorrectly").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = numberIncorrect
ActivePresentation.Slides(41).Shapes("InCorrectPercentage").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = numberPercentage & " %"
MsgBox "Your score was below 70%, in order to pass the quiz and receive a certificate of completion you need to score 70% or more."
MsgBox "Please retake the quiz, and good luck"
With SlideShowWindows(1).View
.GotoSlide 1
End With
' I will add the option of redoing the entire presentation or just the quiz.
'see slide 19 action buttons
End Sub

Sub CertificateBuld()
MsgBox "Great Job, Well done " + "," & "Plese print a copy of your completion certificate"
MsgBox "After printing or saving a copy of your certificate, please exit the presentation"

If numberCorrect >= "14" Then
ActivePresentation.Slides(42).Shapes(" ABCDEFGHIJKLMN ").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMN "
ActivePresentation.Slides(42).Shapes("Rdate & Percentage").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = " ON " & Rdate & " WITH A SCORE OF  " & numberPercentage & " %"
ActivePresentation.Slides(42).Shapes(UserName).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = UserName

'OR

If numberCorrect <= "14" Then
ActivePresentation.Slides(42).Shapes(8).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ABCDEFGHIJKLMN "
ActivePresentation.Slides(42).Shapes(9).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Rdate & " ON " & Rdate & " WITH A SCORE OF  " & numberPercentage & " %"
ActivePresentation.Slides(42).Shapes(10).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = UserName
Else
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Save
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Exit
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

See comments inline:

```
Sub shapeTextHappySmile()
' This won't work:
'ActivePresentation.Slides(40).Shapes(Label1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = 12
' Shapes have names that are strings, so you need to use .Shapes("Label1")
' Assuming this is an ActiveX label, you get at its properties a bit 
' differently from regular PPT shapes, starting with:
' .Shapes("Label1").OLEFormat.Object
' And for a Label ActiveX control, the property you want is .Caption
' And finally, Text/Caption properties take a String value so you want to 
' put the 12 in quotes or convert a numeric value to string using Cstr(x)
' Final version:

ActivePresentation.Slides(40).Shapes("Label1").OLEFormat.Object.Caption = "12"

'numberCorrect

' And make the same changes to this one:
ActivePresentation.Slides(40).Shapes(Label2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = numberPercentage & "%"

' MsgBox "Great Job, Well done " + "," & "Please print a copy of your completion certificate"

' and I think you probably want to do this instead of the above:
MsgBox "Great Job, Well done" & ", " & "Please print a copy of your completion certificate"


MsgBox "After printing or saving a copy of your certificate, you can exit the presentation"
With SlideShowWindows(1).View
.GotoSlide 42
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for the suggested changes.  I was able to modify my script to the point where it works until it is time to insert selected variables such as [username, date, percentage ] onto a form.  On that form I have created lables for the three items and still cannot get them on the form. this is my new code.   Do I use a label or Textbox  to insert the information on to the form on slide 42.   I was hoping the information in the sub Correct() would solve my problem but it did not.  Any new ideas.  I know the date format is off, way off .. No space left for my code.

Comment: Code in comments turns into a jumbled mess; I'd edit your original post and add the code there or start a new question. But in answer to your other question, my changes to your code were based on the assumption that you were using a label control, where you use the .Caption property to set its text. If you change to a TextBox control, use its .Text property instead.

Comment: Okay, I am trying everything. I spent most of the day reading VBA post on how to do things.  until I find something that works.  The I will start a new small project.  I do not know what to use.     I will   logon and delete my last post shortly.